# Up/Downgrade iOS on Linux

Tags: iphone, ipod, ios

Is there a way to Up/Downgrade the iOS of my iPod touch 2G under linux (especially debian)?

I have already read about idevicerecovery but this project doesn't seem to be maintained anymore and therfore pretty messed up.

Answer (score 1):

iTunes can run under Wine, with some difficulty.  Be prepared for it to consume 1GB of Vmem.